# I Can't make RewriteBase and RewriteRule to work properly

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

My structure is the following:

mywebsite/clubeadv/

Inside that folder I have a file called site.php which receives a parameter id.

So, the physical path would be:

mywebsite/clubeadv/site.php?id=something

But I want it to look like this:

mywebsite/clubeadv/site/something

(where 'something' is my parameter)

HOW DO I CONFIGURE THE .HTACCESS FILE?

I tried the following:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^site/(.*)$ site.php?id=$1
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Your DOCUMENT_ROOT is mywebsite or mywebsite/clubeadv ? Also what is the URI in your browser that you want to handle?

Comment: Where is your .htaccess with this code located?

Comment: I tried putting the .htaccess inside the clubeadv folder

Comment: and also inside the mywebsite folder

Comment: I want it to be like this:
www.website.com/mywebsite/site/abc
(www.website.com/mywebsite/site.php?id=abc)

Comment: You still didn't answer my DOCUMENT_ROOT question. When you type `www.website.com/index.html` then from what physical path index.html is loaded? It appears to me that your DOCUMENT_ROOT is one directory above `mywebsite/` folder but want to crosscheck before solving your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the RewriteBase and placing the .htaccess inside your "clubeadv" folder. If your .htaccess is at the root within the "mywebsite" folder, then you could lave the RewriteBase but use `RewriteRule clubeadv/site/(.*)$ clubeadv/site.php?id=$1`

Either way, I'm pretty sure the "^site" causes it to look for mywebsite/site/something in your case.

Comment: It didn't work. Where should the .htaccess file be located? I tried under the mywebsite folder and also under the clubeadv folder.

Comment: As you're rewriting just the clubeadv folder - start by placing the .htaccess there. Also are you sure that .htaccess is allowed on your web host? Try adding an htaccess with random illigal strings, just something like `AAA BBB CCC` in it. If it causes an internal server error when you try to access the site, .htaccess is enabled, otherwise .htaccess is disabled.

Comment: I tried the random illegal strings idea and got nothing. So I guess it is disabled, where do I enable it?

Comment: Talk to your web hosting company, they are the only ones that should be able to tell you if you can use htaccess overrides and how to enable it on their servers. It's typically disabled for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /clubeadv/
RewriteRule . site.php?id=%{REQUEST_URI}
```

That will handle URLs like www.<>.com/clubeadv/abc/edf as site.php?id=/abc/edf.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the problem was the server configuration. To enable .htaccess files, we had to:

- Have the following module loaded:

LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

- Enable override for needed websites under 'directory' tag:

  AllowOverride All

Thank you to those who answered.